# Calculate difference between one observation and all other observations by group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, sapply

I am trying to create the Distance between the first observation and all other observations within a group. The first observation within group A is a1 and group B is b1.

I want a new column in df,"Euclidean', that would have the distance of each observation from the first observation calculated by group.

```
 df <- data.table(Section = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 4),
                                 ID = c('a1','a2','a3','a4','b1','b2','b3','b4'),
                                  x = c(5,10,15,15,10,15,30,25),
                                  y = c(12,10,8,4,6,8,16,24))
```

Where distance calculation would be euclidean[a1,a2] = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2). The first value in each group would be 0. I am hoping to accomplish this using dplyr or data.table.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions with `dplyr`:

(1) By Euclidean distance formula

```
df %>% group_by(Section) %>%
  mutate(Euclidean = sqrt((x - x[1])^2 + (y - y[1])^2))
```

(2) By base function `dist()`

```
df %>% group_by(Section) %>%
  mutate(Euclidean = as.matrix(dist(cbind(x, y)))[1, ])
```

**Note:** The second way is more flexible if you need to change the power of the **Minkowski** distance. If you want the distance from other observations, just adjust the number in the square brackets.

---

Output:

```
#   Section ID        x     y Euclidean
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 A       a1        5    12      0   
# 2 A       a2       10    10      5.39
# 3 A       a3       15     8     10.8 
# 4 A       a4       15     4     12.8 
# 5 B       b1       10     6      0   
# 6 B       b2       15     8      5.39
# 7 B       b3       30    16     22.4 
# 8 B       b4       25    24     23.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
setDT(df)[, Distance := sqrt((x[1]-x)^2+(y[1]-y)^2), .(Section)]
```